# 'willRotateToInterfaceOrientation' not working for my DetailViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm developing this application on the iPad. My MainWindow contains a Split View Controller which loads the RootViewController and DetailViewController.
I have this image that is placed at the bottom-right of the DetailViewController.
My application allows different orientations, therefore i want the image to appear at different positions for different orientations.

This is my code in DetailViewController:

```
- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
  if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
  {
      myImage.frame = CGRectMake(183.0f, 257.0f, 548.0f, 447.0f); 
  }
  else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
  {
      myImage.frame = CGRectMake(244.0f, 518.0f, 548.0f, 447.0f);
  }
}
```

When i launch my application and my iPad is at portrait orientation, the image will be correctly placed at (X:244, Y:518) which is at the bottom right.
But when i launch my application and my iPad is at landscape orientation, the image will not be shown and i suspect that it is still at the position for portrait orientation. Only when i rotate my iPad to portrait orientation and then back to landscape orientation, then the image will appear at (X:183, Y:257) which is correct.

What i tried to do is to place these codes in my DetailViewController's 'viewWillAppear' method:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{ 
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  if(self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
  {
      myImage.frame = CGRectMake(183.0f, 257.0f, 548.0f, 447.0f); 
  }
  else if(self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
  {
      myImage.frame = CGRectMake(244.0f, 518.0f, 548.0f, 447.0f);
  }
}
```

But when i launch my application, it still has the same problem.

What can i do so that when i first launch my application in landscape orientation, it will be correctly placed at (X:244, Y:518) ?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try putting your resizing logic in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` instead of `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`.

My custom layout code only worked when I called it after the rotation had completed it, rather than before.

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
  NSLog(@"didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation");

  float width;
  float height;

  if ((fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) || 
      (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft))
  {
    width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width;
    height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.height;
    NSLog(@"Changing to portrait: %f x %f", width, height);
  }
  else
  {
    width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.height;
    height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width;
    NSLog(@"Changing to landscape: %f x %f", width, height);
  }

  NSLog(@"Changed orientation: %f x %f", width, height);

  // Call my custom layout function to setFrame on all my UI controls
  [self doLayout:width height:height];

  [super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];
}
```

If your app shows the status bar then you probably need to call `self.view.frame.size.width` instead of getting the size from the `applicationFrame`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're overriding

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation; // Override to allow rotation. Default returns YES only for UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
```

To return YES for each UIInterfaceOrentation that you want to support, otherwise willRotateToInterfaceOrientation and didRotateToInterfaceOrientation wont get called.

Comment: Yes i did return YES for that. It gets called when i tried to rotate my iPad, and the position of the image did change. The problem is when i first launch the application in landscape mode, the image is still at the position it should be when in portrait mode. I have to rotate my iPad to portrait, then back to landscape, to make my image change it's position to where it should be when in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling this early in your applicationDidFinishLauching:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `detailViewController` wouldn't sometimes know its orientation, I solved this issue by having a shared variable in the `appDelegate` that would store the device orientation throughout the app. You can initialize it in the `splitViewController` with its orientation so when the `detailViewController` loads it can read it from there.

Comment: You can also read the orientation from [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation